# FLUTTER DOCTOR. FileSystemException error_message

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have installed flutter and android studio on my pc but I'm having difficulty completing my pc set-up. I ran the "flutter doctor" command after installation but got the following error message below.

***[☠] Android Studio (the doctor check crashed)
X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
X FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = '=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio.plugins' (OS Error: The
filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, errno = 123)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is due to whitespaces in the path. I had the same error and changed the path from "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" to a short representation "C:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1". I.e. ran flutter config --android-studio-dir C:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1\ After that, all checks succeed.